# Socket is not connected Pepper

Tags: pepper, qi

I use pythonsdk and naoqi for programming my pepper robot. i created a session and call the main by it is follows:

```
    try
       session = qi.Session()
       session.connect("tcp://#.#.#.#:9559")

    except RuntimeError:
       print ("Cannot connect to robot ")

    main(session)
```

each run of my program may take about 2 hourse. Actually it is a toutrial based interaction which is a loop of two phase: robot speech and playing a video clip on pepper's tablet, then a new topic and new video clip and so on. 
but after a while i got these errors:

```
RuntimeError: Session not connected.
RuntimeError: Socket is not connected
```

so what these errors mean? and how can i overcome them? Thanks in advance

[image: session not connected]

Comment: is your robot or naoqi crashed when this happens? or are you able to reconnect the sessions afterwards ?

Comment: I can reconnect immediately after  it,

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your session remains alive, by using it from the scope it was created:

```py
session = qi.Session()
session.connect("tcp://#.#.#.#:9559")
main(session)
```

Comment: I exactly used the same code for creating my session,